# About Multithreading with GUIs in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, invoke

I was reading that example that I am going to post and what I don't understand is this:
They say that if I want to perform an interaction with the GUI it has to be done by the UI thread.In other words: using the .Invoke method of the Controll class. In the example I don't understand why we are using the `output.Invoke...` in the `GenerateRandomCharacters` method where the output is being changed but in the `Toggle()` where the output is also being changed (its color) there is no `.Invoke` ? Isn't it the same?

```
public class RandomLetters
{
    private static Random generator = new Random(); // for random letters
    private bool suspended = false; // true if thread is suspended
    private Label output; // Label to display output
    private string threadName; // name of the current thread

   // RandomLetters constructor
   public RandomLetters( Label label )
   {
      output = label;
   } // end RandomLetters constructor

   // delegate that allows method DisplayCharacter to be called
   // in the thread that creates and maintains the GUI
   private delegate void DisplayDelegate( char displayChar );

   // method DisplayCharacter sets the Label's Text property
   private void DisplayCharacter( char displayChar )
   {
   // output character in Label
      output.Text = threadName + ": " + displayChar;
   } // end method DisplayCharacter

   // place random characters in GUI
   public void GenerateRandomCharacters()
   {
   // get name of executing thread
      threadName = Thread.CurrentThread.Name;

      while ( true ) // infinite loop; will be terminated from outside
      {
      // sleep for up to 1 second
         Thread.Sleep( generator.Next( 1001 ) );

         lock ( this ) // obtain lock
         {
           while ( suspended ) // loop until not suspended
           {
             Monitor.Wait( this ); // suspend thread execution
           } // end while
         } // end lock
         // select random uppercase letter
         char displayChar = ( char ) ( generator.Next( 26 ) + 65 );

         // display character on corresponding Label
         output.Invoke( new DisplayDelegate( DisplayCharacter ),
         new object[] { displayChar } );
      } // end while
    } // end method GenerateRandomCharacters

    // change the suspended/running state
    public void Toggle()
    {
       suspended = !suspended; // toggle bool controlling state

       // change label color on suspend/resume
       output.BackColor = suspended ? Color.Red : Color.LightGreen;

       lock ( this ) // obtain lock
       {
          if ( !suspended ) // if thread resumed
          Monitor.Pulse( this );
       } // end lock
     } // end method Toggle
  } // end class RandsomLetters
```

**EDIT:** And here it is the actual call:

```
public partial class GUIThreadsForm : Form
{
    public GUIThreadsForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    } // end constructor

    private RandomLetters letter1; // first RandomLetters object
    private RandomLetters letter2; // second RandomLetters object
    private RandomLetters letter3; // third RandomLetters object

    private void GUIThreadsForm_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        // create first thread
        letter1 = new RandomLetters( thread1Label );
        Thread firstThread = new Thread(
            new ThreadStart( letter1.GenerateRandomCharacters ) );
        firstThread.Name = "Thread 1";
        firstThread.Start();

        continues...
```

---

This is the way Toggle() method is being called:

```
private void threadCheckBox_CheckedChanged( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    if ( sender == thread1CheckBox )
        letter1.Toggle();
    else if ( sender == thread2CheckBox )
        letter2.Toggle();
    else if ( sender == thread3CheckBox )
        letter3.Toggle();
} // end method threadCheckBox_CheckedChanged
```

After a checkbox control is activated in CheckedChanged event and it gets into the Toggle() method

Comment: "infinite loop; will be terminated from outside" You aren't calling `Thread.Abort`, aren't you?! That's very dangerous.

Comment: @usr No, I am not. There is a CheckBox control that after being checked the thread has to be suspended.

Comment: May I suggest a rewording of the question's title?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably whatever is calling this class's methods is only ever calling `GenerateRandomCharacters` from a non-UI thread, and `Toggle` is only ever being called from the UI thread, hence why only `GenerateRandomCharacters` needs to explicitly marshal to the UI thread.

You would need to see how these methods are called to verify that.